# Which countries, regions, or cities have zero emission vehicle mandates?

Tags: greenhouse-gas-emissions, usa, electric-vehicles, vehicle, law

Today the governor of the U.S. state of Massachusetts [announced](https://www.mass.gov/news/baker-polito-administration-releases-roadmap-to-achieve-net-zero-emissions-by-2050) that starting in 2035, gasoline-powered vehicles will no longer be sold in the state. From the announcement (emphasis added, and a "sic" indicating where some words appear to have been left out by mistake):

> The transportation sector highlights a renewed focus on the deployment of electric vehicles with new, nation-leading state and regional programs including the Transportation and Climate Initiative Program. Building on that progress, **Massachusetts will join California in requiring that by 2035, 100% of new light-duty vehicles sold in the Commonwealth are zero emission vehicles (ZEVs)** [*sic*] support the continued build-out of statewide charging infrastructure, including additional consumer incentives for residential EV charging systems.

This announcement mentions a similar requirement in California, and recently I heard that [New Jersey is working on something too](https://nj.gov/governor/news/news/562020/approved/20200714a.shtml).

**Which countries, regions, or cities currently have requirements or targets to eliminate or reduce sale of carbon-emitting vehicles? What are the specifics of the plans?**

Comment: I'm not sure if it's complete, but [this wiki post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-out_of_fossil_fuel_vehicles#Cities_and_territories) mentions only California and Massachusetts (and 3 US cities; Los Angeles, New York and Seattle). So maybe there are no other US states that finalized this yet?